# I'm trying to use django login view and get NoReverseMatch error during rendering base template

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-login

Please, help!
I'm really stuck, I'm trying to make login page using django login view and time after time I'm getting NoReverseMatch error on rendering base template.

In the documentation I read about tag url, but I don't understand how to use it.

Here is my base template

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="ru">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title></title>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/bootstrap/bootstrap-grid-3.3.1.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/countdown/jquery.countdown.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fonts pariszanka.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/media.css" />
</head>
<style>
 *::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 color: #666;
 opacity: 1;
}
*:-moz-placeholder {
 color: #666;
 opacity: 1;
}
*::-moz-placeholder {
 color: #666;
 opacity: 1;
}
*:-ms-input-placeholder {
 color: #666;
 opacity: 1;
}
html {
   position: relative;
   min-height: 100%;
}
body {
   margin-bottom: 60px;
   background-color: #d7dad9;
}
.header{
 font-family: IsadoraBold;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 30px;
 }
.top_line{
 background-color: #24292E;
 color: white;
}
.bottom_line{
 background-color: #24292E;
 color: white;
}
.top_name{
 float: left;
 list-style-type: none;
}
.top_nav{
 float: right;
}
.top_nav ul li{
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: center;
 padding-right: 40px;
}
.top_nav a{
 color: white;
}
.top_nav a:hover{
 color: #78B0AE;
}

</style>


<body>
<div class="top_line">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="row">
    <ul class="hidden-md hidden-lg hidden-xl top_name">
     <li><h1>JFE</h1></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="top_name hidden-sm hidden-xs">
     <h1>Jobs For Everybody</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="top_nav">
     <ul>
      {% if user.is_authenticated %}
      <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><h4>Главная</h4></a></li>
      <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="/notes"><h4>Заметки</h4></a></li>
      <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="/sred_zp"><h4>Рассчет средней З/П</h4></a></li>
      <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="/logout"><h4>{{user.username}}</h4></a></li>
              {% endif %}
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
 <div class="col-md-12">
  {% block content %}{% endblock %}
 </div>
</div>

<div class="navbar-fixed-bottom">
 <div class="bottom_line">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
     <center><h3>Jobs For Everybody</h3></center>
     <center><h4>MartsinovichDanya copyright 2019</h4></center>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>


 <script src="libs/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="libs/jquery-mousewheel/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
 <script src="libs/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
 <script src="libs/waypoints/waypoints-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="libs/scrollto/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
 <script src="libs/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
 <script src="libs/countdown/jquery.plugin.js"></script>
 <script src="libs/countdown/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
 <script src="libs/countdown/jquery.countdown-ru.js"></script>
 <script src="libs/landing-nav/navigation.js"></script>
 <script src="js/common-pariszanka.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my login template that extends base template

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <style>
    .button{
        width: 25%;
    }
    p input{
        border-width: 2px;
     border-color: gray;
     border-radius: 30px;
     padding: 15px 10px;
     margin-top: 10px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     background-color: 8F8E89;
     width: 40%;
 }
 p label{
     margin-top: 15px;
 }
 form a{
     font-size: 20px;
     color: 6E6D68;
    }
    form a:hover{
     font-size: 20px;
     color: #78B0AE;
    }
    </style>

    {% url 'login' %}

    {% if form.errors %}
    <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
    {% endif %}

    {% if next %}
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <p>Your account doesn't have access to this page. To proceed,
        please login with an account that has access.</p>
        {% else %}
        <p>Please login to see this page.</p>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}

    <form method="post" action="{% url django.contrib.auth.views.login %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
        <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
        <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="login">
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
    </form>

    {# Assumes you setup the password_reset view in your URLconf #}
    <p><a href="{% url 'password_reset' %}">Lost password?</a></p>

    {% endblock %}
```

Here is a part of settings.py

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'JobsForEverybody_app',
    'Notes_app',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'JobsForEverybody.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            '/home/danya/PycharmProjects/JobsForEverybody-JFE_website/templates'
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Here is urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('JobsForEverybody_app.urls')),
    path('index', include('JobsForEverybody_app.urls')),
    path('login', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html')),
    path('logout', include('JobsForEverybody_app.urls')),
    path('registration', include('JobsForEverybody_app.urls')),
    path('settings', include('JobsForEverybody_app.urls')),
    path('delete_vacancy/<int:vac_id>', include('JobsForEverybody_app.urls')),
]
```

[image: The screenshot of error]

Answer (score 0):

the error is because you didn't added name to `login` url.

in `urls.py` for login urlpattern add `name`

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('login', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html'), name='login'),
```